# DevTools failed to load SourceMap:

Tags: javascript, shopify

From my website: https://www.fermento24.com/
When we go analyzing the website with google, I get some errors, and while 've got the gist of the other errors, this error in particular is difficult:
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/0383/0855/t/12/assets/swiper.min.js.map:
HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Now, I understand that the file in question is missing, but... WHAT is calling to this file? And how do I go and fix this? I don't think this file was really deleted, but most likely changed...

hope someone will answer

Comment: you need to check the file `swiper.js` in the very end `map` file URL is added, remove it, no need to add it.

Comment: Hrm. Got it. But... where does this get called from? I've got no idea on where to change the call of this link in the theme.
Note: I've checked the theme assets, and swiper.js is there, so its just a matter that, for some reason, this .map is added... Any suggestions?

Comment: Are able to share the link if swiper.js?

Comment: should be this: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/0383/0855/t/12/assets/swiper.js
As you can see, it is the same as the link in the could not load, but without the .min and .map . I know that.min is minimization of the file, and its done automatically etc., but I do not know what is attaching this .map

Comment: Remove this end of link code https://prnt.sc/z4dq8j for the file and save it, and then check it resolve the warning issue into console.

Comment: Yup, deleting this whole link at the end did it. Thank you Onkar.